# Function not filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function that is supposed to filter through a js array and show only items with the same category name for example "Top" and nothing is happening when i click the button.

Console sends this warning: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
const [data,setData] = useState(data);
    const filterResult = (categoryItem) =>{
        const result =data.filter((currData)=>{
            return currData.category === categoryItem;
        })
        setData(result);
    }
    return(
    <div>
      button onClick={()=>filterResult("Top")}>Top</button>
    </div>
 

                <div>
            {data.map((nftDetail)=>{
                return  (<>
                    <div className='card' key={nftDetail.id}>
                    <h3>{nftDetail.title}</h3>
                    <h5>{nftDetail.category}</h5>
                    </div>
                    </>)
                })}        
            </div>

)
```

Data used for the map

```
{
    id:1,
    title: "NFT",
    category:"Top"

},
{
    id:2,
    title: "2NFT",
    category:"Trending"

},
{
    id:3,
    title: "3NFT",
    category:"Art"

},
{
    id:4,
    title: "4NFT",
    category:"Sports"

},
{
    id:5,
    title: "5NFT",
    category:"Top"

}
```

]

Comment: The warning is not related, it's just saying since you have `data.map`, suggesting you to not use `fragment` and should assign `key` props, your code looks fine, at least for the filtering & updating state logic

Comment: filter is working fine https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-wilson-klinl

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  @shubhamjha  I used the sandbox code in my js file and it worked. Im now working over that.